# Find 2nd largest element from stdin without using an array

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, m1, m2, n, num;
    puts("\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         scanf("%d", &num);
         if(i == 0) {
              num = m1 = m2;
         }
         if(num > m1) {
              m2 = m1; 
              m1 = num; 
         } else if(num > m2) {
              m2 = num;
         }
     }
    return 0;
}
```

my stdin: `-950 -588 -169 -187 -445 400 -1`

I have to get stdout: `-169` but its showing stdout: `\n`

Note: I want to solve this problem without arrays.

Comment: Well, you never `printf()` the result...

Comment: @cdhowie can you elaborate briefly.

Comment: When `i == 0`, `num = m1 = m2` overwrites the `num` you read with an undefined value. The code assumes `m1` and `m2` are defined, but initially they aren't.

Comment: @NidhiMurthy I mean that you compute a result but you *never write it out*.  You just throw it away.  If you want your program to have some output, you need to make it write some output.

Comment: my expected output and actual output is not matching. actual output is blank.

Comment: @NidhiMurthy Actual output is blank because **you never write any output**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430108/what-does-it-mean-to-write-to-stdout-in-c

Comment: @cdhowie tell me how can i get correct output.

Comment: @lurker : can you explain briefly. or can you edit program.

Comment: rolling buffer sized 2... is is pretty easy to manage 2 elements without an array...

Comment: @GradyPlayer  how? can you add your code here in answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate ;-/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490946/how-to-find-the-second-largest-element-using-c-program-without-using-array

Comment: @JamesMorris  that was my account only. question was not active so i created another. whats big deal.

Comment: if my answer helped you, why don't you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

the statement:

```
num = m1 = m2;
```

is wrong and it does not cause the three variables to have the same value. You need to assign m1 and m2 to num. You are overwriting the variable that you previously had read. Change it to:

```
m1 = num;
m2 = num;
```

Then, print out the m2.

**EDIT:**

As others found out, the -1 states for end of your input. Adding simple if statement solves the problem and for your input -169 is the second largest element.

Full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int i, m1, m2, n, num;
puts("\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     scanf("%d",&num);
     if(i==0)
     {
          m1 = num;
          m2 = num;
     }
     else if(num == -1)  /* if -1 was read, then terminate the loop. */
     {
         break;
     }
     else if(num>m1)
     {
          m2 = m1; 
          m1 = num; 
     }
     else if(num>m2)
     {
          m2=num;
     }
 }
printf("%d\n",m2);
return 0;
}
```

For input:

```
7
-950 -588 -169 -187 -445 400 -1
```

and current code output is -169.

Another EDIT:

Ok, your code is wrong because of the scanf for number of elements. In future It would be helpful if you were more clear about your problems. I hope that following code will work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int curr, second, first;
    scanf("%d", &curr);
    second = curr;
    first = curr;
    while (1) {
        scanf("%d", &curr);
        if (curr == -1) {
            break;
        }
        if (curr > first) {
            second = first;
            first = curr;
        }
        else if (curr > second) {
            second = curr;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",second);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: actual output and expected output not matching for your code. it gave me this output \n
\n
32767\n

Comment: Yes. -1 is the second largest element in your input. -169 is the third one.

Comment: but its showing 32767 instead -169.  i tried with other test case also  stdin: -840 -288 -261 -337 -335 488 -1 stdout: -32767 instead of -261

Comment: do you provide at first a number of elements that will be read (in your case 7)? Also, in this another set of elements, again -1 is the second largest element.

Comment: Instead of the `continue`, why not just make the next `if` an `else if`?

Comment: @lurker ok, changed that, but I think with continue it was just fine as it is currently.

Comment: Yes it works with the `continue`, but the `else if` is better form. :)

Comment: @NidhiMurthy the solution shown above works fine. If you are seeing `32767` then you have not entered it properly.

Comment: @lurker ok I agree with you :)

Comment: @lurker no i checked 3-4 times. same code i entered. its showing 32767.

Comment: @NidhiMurthy are you under the impression that -1 is supposed to mean, "don't read any more input" rather than being part of the set of numbers?  Because you never stated that, and you original code didn't show that either.

Comment: @JohnH that might be the case. But then, what would be the point of having `scanf("%d",&n);` ?

Comment: @NidhiMurthy ok that's a bit confusing. I ran this code and it works fine using the input shown and yielding the result of `-1`. Can you edit your problem statement and show what your command looks like to compile the code? And as JohnH says, if you want `-1` to terminate your date, then you need to check for it in the code.

Comment: @lurker  i dont have credit to upload my screenshots. new user so i cant upload.

Comment: I've edited my answer and now it does what you're looking for. However, please specify how you compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Program to find the second largest number without using array */
        main()
        {
         int num,large=0,slarge=0,i=0;
         clrscr();
         printf("Enter the number:");
         while(i<10)
         {
          scanf("%d",&num);
          if(i==0)
          {
          large=num;
          }
          else if(num>large)
          {
           slarge=large;
           large=num;
          }
          else if(num>slarge)
          {
           slarge=num;
          }
          i++;
         }
         printf("Large number:%d",large);
         printf("\nSecond large=%d",slarge);
         getch();
         return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are using `m2` uninitialized. To correct the problem, set `m2` to some reasonable negative number (like the smallest integer allowed). Here we are just using a negative number for example:

```
m2 = -1000000;
```

**outout**

```
argument [0]:  -950
argument [1]:  -588
argument [2]:  -169
argument [3]:  -445
argument [4]:  400
argument [5]:  -1

m1: 400
m2: -1
```

Your code does what you intend. `-1` is the second largest number (`400` is the largest). If you want `-169`, then you want the 3rd largest. Remember:

**ALWAYS INITIALIZE YOUR VARIABLES**

Answer (score 0):

here's a working and simpler version :

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <limits.h>

  int main(int argc , char** argv)
  {
    int m1 , m2 , rc = 1;
    m1 = m2 = INT_MIN ;

    while(rc)
    {
            scanf("%d" , &rc);
            if(rc > m1)
                    m1 = rc;
            else if(rc < m1 && rc > m2)
                    m2 = rc;

    }
    printf("%d\n" , m2);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Second largest elements in a given array*/
#include <stdio.h>
int SecondMax(int a[], int n) // n= array size 
{
    int max1, max2;     //assume max1 as largest and max2 is second largest 
    max1= max2= a[0];   //Initialize first element of array
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > max1) //check each elements of array with max1 
        {
            max2= max1; 
            max1= a[i];
        }
        else if(a[i] > max2)
            max2= a[i];
    }
    return max2;
}

int main()  
{
    int a[10]={2, 54, 8, 9 ,12, 6, 3, 7, 32, -5};

    printf("\nmax2= %d", SecondMax(a, 10)); //print return value 
    return 0;
}
```