# What is the complexity of this program?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I want to analyze the execution time complexity of the below program. 
Please answer with the explanation.

```
private static void printSecondLargest(int[] arr) {
    int length = arr.length, temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < length; j++) {
            if(arr[i]<arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Second largest is: "+arr[1]);
}
```

Comment: The inner loop runs `(2* arr.length)-2` times *totally*. The complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: O(n) is the complexity of program.

Comment: @TheLostMind thanks for answering. However your answer is correct but the explanation is slightly incorrect. it'll execute (2* arr.length) - 3 times.

Comment: @RahulChaubey - Ya right. 1 +2 --> 3.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's O(*n*) where *n* represents the length of the array.

The body of the inner most loop:

```
if(arr[i]<arr[j]) {
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

runs in constant time.

This code will be executed first `arr.length-1` times, then `arr.length-2` times. That is `2 * arr.length - 3`. Thus the execution time is proportional to 2n-3 which is O(*n*).

Comment: How did you get 4n? Two executions = 2n?

Comment: Thanks aioobe. Do u know any better approach to solve it in C?

Comment: You can't do better than O(n), but see for instance [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490946/how-to-find-the-second-largest-element-using-c-program-without-using-array) for alternative implementatios. Also, please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @bigdestroyer, code won't execute (2*n -3) twice. it will n-1 first time and n-2 second time, so n-1 + n-2 = 2n-3 in total.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly O(n). The outer loop is running only 2 times and inner loop N times. So, overall complexity is O(2*n).

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop will run two times and inner loop runs (length-1) and second time (length-2)

suppose length is N

`so it will be 2*((N-1)/2+(N-2/)2)==2*(2n-3)/2`

```
Which is final (2N-3) and in O notation it is O(N)
```

Comment: `(N-2/)2`? And where does `/2` come from to begin with?

Comment: common LCM of N-1/2 and N-2/2:-)

Comment: Yup average of two inner iteration

Comment: But averaging is completely redundant. You must *sum* all the runtimes, not *average* them.

Comment: Actually i used 2* in the initial step which is representing the number of iterations of the loop so i have to take the average of time consumed by all :-)
And sorry yup it is redundant :-)

Comment: Should i delete the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printSecondLargest(int[] arr) {    
    int length = arr.length, temp;    // **it takes contant time**
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {     // as loop goes only two step it also takes constant time
        for (int j = i+1; j < length; j++) {   // this loop takes n time if we consider arr length of size n
            if(arr[i]<arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];    // it also takes constant time
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Second largest is: "+arr[1]);
}
```

So as per above calculation we neglect constant time and calculate all varying time constraint and as per code complexity will be `O(n)`.