# Find second highest number without using array

Tags: c

You are given a sequence of integers as input, terminated by a -1. (That is, the input integers may be positive, negative or 0. A -1 in the input signals the end of the input.)

-1 is not considered as part of the input.

Find the second largest number in the input. You may not use arrays.

Test cases pass but score is 0.0

Here's the code

```
int main()
{
    int a=-32768,b=-32768,temp=-32768;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if(a==-1)
            break;
        else if(a>0)
        {
            temp=b;
            b=a;

        }
        else
        {
            if(a>b)
            {
                temp=b;
                b=a;
            }
            else
            {
                temp=b;
            }
        }

    }
    printf("%d",temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried so far and what's not working?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for the very simple input like this :: `7 6 3 4 1 2 3 5  -1` Expected output `6` your code output `3`http://ideone.com/yHacZG

Comment: Look at your `if-else` statements. Work through an example like what user007 posted and see what happens because of how your statements are structured. You'd rarely enter the final part of the outer `if-else` chain, do you see that?

Comment: Previous iterations of this exact same question: [last week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476653/finding-the-second-largest-elementyou-may-not-use-arrays-in-c), [last year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490946/how-to-find-the-second-largest-element-using-c-program-without-using-array)

Comment: Your code is actually printing second last number entered.

Comment: Have a downvote because of 'a', 'b'.  Next time you write homework, try using descriptive var names like 'largest', 'secondLargest'.

Comment: Debugger, debugger....

Comment: As the numbers input may be negative (except for the flag `-1`) I don't see the relevance of the test `if(a>0)` or indeed why it's preceded by an `else`.

Comment: Just in case you are still in trouble, u might want to look at some answers to this! Might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490946/how-to-find-the-second-largest-element-using-c-program-without-using-array?lq=1 Exactly the same question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad check of value in your way.
For example, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EOI -1 //End Of Input

int main(void){
    int input, first, second;

    first = second = EOI;

    while(1){
        if(1 != scanf("%d", &input)){
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input!\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if(input == EOI)
            break;
        if(first == EOI){
            first = input;
        } else if(first <= input){
            second = first;//slide
            first = input;
        } else if(second == EOI || second < input){
            second = input;
        }
    }
    if(second == EOI){//first == EOI || second == EOI
        fprintf(stderr, "No valid value is entered more than one!\n");
        return -2;
    }
    printf("%d\n", second);
    return 0;
}
```